# When checking box how to redirect_to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

When checking a box how can the page automatically `redirect_to @habit`? This behavior would be similar to hitting a submit button.

**habits/show**

```
  <% if @habit.current_level_strike %> 
    <div class="btn" id="red"> <label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id">Strikes:</label>
  <% else %> 
    <div class="btn" id="gold"> <label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id-two">Strikes:</label>
  <% end %>
    <% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
      <% if @habit.current_level >= (index + 1) %>
        <p>
          <% if @habit.current_level_strike %> 
            <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id">Level <%= index + 1 %>:</label> 
          <% else %> 
            <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id-two">Level <%= index + 1 %>:</label> 
          <% end %>
          <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>
          <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 1, {class: "habit-check"} %>
          <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 2, {class: "habit-check"} %>
       </p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

**habit.js**

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() 
{
  $(".habit-check").change(function()
  {
    habit = $(this).parent().siblings(".habit-id").first().attr("id");
    level = $(this).siblings(".level-id").first().attr("id");
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed",
         method: "POST"
       });
    }
    else
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed/1",
         method: "DELETE"
       });
    }
  });
});
```

**days_missed_controller**

```
class DaysMissedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    @habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    if level.missed_days == 3
      level.missed_days = 0
      level.days_lost += habit.calculate_days_lost + 1
    end
    level.save!
    redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Added Strike Against You!' # This message pops up once the user manually goes to a new page, but I'd want the page to automatically redirect_to @habit so that the show page can refresh with the new number of strikes
    head :ok
  end
```

[**The larger issue is this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056718/sometimes-checkmark-disappears-in-production?noredirect=1#comment50135074_31056718), but I think implementing this feature might help me further clarify what the larger problem is.

Comment: What is the larger problem, I dont want to follow a link to find out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you would like to "refresh" the page the user is currently on. You can do something like this in you *habit.js* (`done` is executed when any of your AJAX calls is finished):

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() 
{
  $(".habit-check").change(function()
  {
    // ...

    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed",
         method: "POST"
       })
       .done(function () {
         location.reload();
       });
    }
    else
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed/1",
         method: "DELETE"
       })
       .done(function () {
         location.reload();
       });
    }
  });
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: I decided to take out turbolinks because it made submitting act funky on mobile devices along with a few other quirks associated with it. Hopefully it won't slow down the web app too much.

Comment: Well, I'd say you wont have any penalty for not-using turbolinks. It's more not to gain the boost it can give you, so there's nothing horrible about getting rid of it

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the location of the page without needing to go to the server.

In JavaScript:

```
var habitURL = '<%= raw(habit_url(@habit)) %>';

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  if($(this).prop('checked')) { // Only when it is changed to checked
    window.location = habitURL;
  }
});
```